# onHover events in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change a margin-right value with a onHover event that triggers when cursor is actually on .one (for example) and turns back normal when cursor is not on .one

This is what I've done:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if 
        $(".sidebar .navicon").hover(function() {
        $(".sidebarwrap").css('margin-right', "0");
    });

    else{
        $(".sidebarwrap").css('margin-right', "-345px");
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: If I move the cursor away from .navicon (that is child of .sidebarwrap) margin-right turns back to "-345px" (its default value) and I don't want it! It would be much more easier in CSS but as I said, I can't do this kind of stuff because I want to affect parent css by an event that affect its child

Comment: `.hover` is the event - perhaps you should do this in css with a class?

Comment: I can't, I'm trying to change CSS value of a element that is parent of the one that will trigger the event itself. I need jQuery or javascript for this kind of stuff

Answer (score 6):

The `hover` event work with 2 functions, not with `if` and `else`, check this simple example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sidebar .navicon").hover(function() {
        $(".sidebarwrap").css('margin-left', "50px");
    }, function() {
        $(".sidebarwrap").css('margin-left', "0");
    });
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/2eqv291v/1/)

[Learn more here](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Comment: Replace div with .sidebar .navicon, this might help him... ;)

Comment: I upvoted your answer, i think it is what he is looking for, upvote my previous comment if you think is useful.. @lmgonzalves ...

Comment: Your tip is very helpful but if I move cursor .sidebarwrap starts to "shake" (margin-right change its value very fast) probably because cursor isn't on .sidebar .navicon anymore. Maybe it's better if I explain myself better.. I'm going to edit first post!

Comment: @hiru If you want set a margin on `hover`, but not "reset" it when mouse is out, you can use `mouseenter` event instead `hover`. See an example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/2eqv291v/2/). If that is not what you want, then you need to explain better your requirements.

Comment: This is a version of what I've done in pure CSS: http://gfycat.com/RemarkableImmenseGiraffe
As you can see sidebar triggers when cursor goes hover it, but I want to trigger sidebar ONLY when cursor is on that symbol, and stay opened, (this: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/bars/) but not when it's on sidebar itself

Comment: You want to show the sidebar when you `hover` the icon, understood. But I don't understand how it should work once the sidebar is displayed.